# Do I need to import the module where the class is defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm new to Python. I'm working on code that follows the following structure.

**a.py**

```
class A:
    # ...

# some `def`s
```

**b.py**

```
import a

class B:
    # ...

def create_b_from_a(a_obj):
    # reads fields from the instance of A
    # never instantiates an A
    # never uses anything from a.py
```

Is the `import a` really necessary? Does Python need the import to determine which fields are defined in instances of `A`?

Comment: Remove the import and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `import a` is only necessary if you need to make an explicit reference to something in module `a`. If you never need to say `a.something`, you shouldn't need the import. IIUC, you don't need the `import a` in your case since you got an `A` object from somewhere else, your code knows implicitly how to work on objects of that type, and you don't explicitly need anything new from module `a`.